# Does article THE in "made in THE usa" legal?

Tags: articles

Today in Google I notice a song "Demi Lovato - Made in the USA". All my life I thoought that the correct form is "Made in (COUNTRY)". For example: "Made in China". Many products has that title)

So, why is "THE"?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name